# React: Reset const

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to perform a reset of the following const:

```
const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
```

that is contained in a child componenent named UploadForm.

The variable has to reset when the following const in the parent component, named Upload, is empty:

```
const [partner, setDropDownPartner] = useState('');
```

the change of the partner const in the parent component is handled by an event handler.

Unfortunately, I am not able to perform a reset in this scenario.

I tried using UseEffect and bind it to a boolean variable in the child component but it works only the first time:

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    if(resetUpload) setDescription(''); setFileToUpload();     
 
 }, [resetUpload]);
```

Can you point me to the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to perform the emptiness check whenever the `partner` state changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (partner === '') {
    setDescription('');
  },
  [partner]
);
```

Comment: the problem is that the description const is defined in the parent. I tried your code but it gives me the following error: ./src/Page/UploadJson.js
  Line 55:9:  'setDescription' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @OuterSpace This code is supposed to reside in the `UploadForm` component. You can pass the `partner` prop from the parent (`Upload`) to the child using this syntax: `<UploadForm partner={partner} />`. In the `UploadForm` you define a prop named `partner` and use it as a dependency there.